# Why does mypy generate different errors depending on running with `.` vs path to specific file?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Versions:

```
Python 3.9.1
mypy==0.910
```

I'm unsure why mypy will output a different set of errors when run with `mypy .` vs running with `mypy <path to file>`

When running `mypy . --strict --show-error-codes` the result is different to doing `mypy <path to file> --strict --show-error-codes`.

For example, looking at code from https://github.com/raphaelvallat/pingouin (commit id `ea8b560`, file being used as an example here is: `https://github.com/raphaelvallat/pingouin/blob/f40df480e137af8df35a3a3164d2d900b79091a6/pingouin/utils.py#L10`).

Running :  `mypy . --strict --show-error-codes  --exclude "./venv/"` gives:

```
(venv) ➜  pingouin git:(master) ✗ mypy . --strict --show-error-codes  --exclude "./venv/" > mypy_all_files.txt
(venv) ➜  pingouin git:(master) ✗ grep "pingouin/utils.py" mypy_all_files.txt
pingouin/utils.py:3: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "numpy"  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:4: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "pandas"  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:7: error: Library stubs not installed for "tabulate" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:7: note: Hint: "python3 -m pip install types-tabulate"
pingouin/utils.py:7: note: (or run "mypy --install-types" to install all missing stub packages)
pingouin/utils.py:440: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "statsmodels"  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:454: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "sklearn"  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:468: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "mpmath"  [import]
```

And running `mypy ./pingouin/utils.py --strict --show-error-codes > mypy_single_file.txt` gives:

```
(venv) ➜  pingouin git:(master) ✗ mypy ./pingouin/utils.py --strict --show-error-codes > mypy_single_file.txt
(venv) ➜  pingouin git:(master) ✗ grep "pingouin/utils.py" mypy_single_file.txt
pingouin/utils.py:3: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "numpy"  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:3: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
pingouin/utils.py:4: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "pandas"  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:7: error: Library stubs not installed for "tabulate" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:7: note: Hint: "python3 -m pip install types-tabulate"
pingouin/utils.py:7: note: (or run "mypy --install-types" to install all missing stub packages)
pingouin/utils.py:16: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:54: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:78: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:113: error: Call to untyped function "_get_round_setting_for" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:140: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:157: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:176: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:225: error: Call to untyped function "_remove_na_single" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:227: error: Call to untyped function "_remove_na_single" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:232: error: Call to untyped function "_remove_na_single" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:235: error: Call to untyped function "_remove_na_single" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:236: error: Call to untyped function "_remove_na_single" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:260: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:303: error: Call to untyped function "_flatten_list" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:341: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:379: error: Call to untyped function "_flatten_list" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:382: error: Call to untyped function "_flatten_list" in typed context  [no-untyped-call]
pingouin/utils.py:390: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:399: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:437: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:440: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "statsmodels"  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:451: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:454: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "sklearn"  [import]
pingouin/utils.py:465: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
pingouin/utils.py:468: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "mpmath"  [import]
```

The latter is what I'd be more interested in seeing, and would expect others to be also.
I'm not sure why there's a difference, and how to go about having the latter output as default.

Comment: I can't replicate this.  What version of `mypy` and `python` are you using?

Comment: This feels like a regression.  I updated from `mypy` 0.770 to 0.910 and I'm seeing similar behavior.

Comment: Sorry, will add versions to post

Comment: Check the bottom of the output for your `mpy .` version.  I have a line like `Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)`.  I think you might as well.  I suppose that means some error in some file stopped `mypy` from continuing to check other files.  I don't know what that behavior exists though.

Comment: My best guess is that it was a change in how `mypy` recursively searches for modules in 0.800.  Check the [changelog](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2021/01/mypy-0800-released.html) and the detailed [searching documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#mapping-paths-to-modules)